# FHIR Sandboxes are of low quality

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I'm currently building an application that leverages FHIR via the HAPI-FHIR api.  Up till now I've been going through the sandboxes listed at [hl7.org fhir sandboxes](http://wiki.hl7.org/index.php?title=Publicly_Available_FHIR_Servers_for_testing) but I have found most of them to have a lot of incomplete/corrupt data.  Can anyone recommend a more useful data test of fhir data?  The best I have found thus far is the sample data provided by hl7.org but it is still very limited (12 patients, 3 medications).

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with sandboxes is that people tend to mess them up.  We're working to get a robust set of rich clinical data that can be used for testing, but for it to remain pristine, you'll probably have to load it on your own test server to avoid it being corrupted by other people testing.

Comment: Thanks Lloyd.  Makes sense, I do have a test server currently, it would be great to see a more pristine data set.